# Can I add other packages and customization in quick start of Texmaker

Tags: texmaker

I am using TexMaker and I do report every week with the preamble of the document similar. I am used to quick start in Texmaker, Currently My quick start gives me these commands

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
```

But I want to also add packages and some customization to my article such as

```
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 }
```

Is there any way, I can integrate the second part to the quick start of texmaker?

Comment: You should use `User / User Tags` menu.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you write the answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own template in `User / User Tags / Edit User Tags`.